# Angular Unit Test with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush doesn't work

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I've got this simple component.

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="loading; else valueTpl">
      <strong>loading....</strong>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #valueTpl>
      <span>{{ value }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
  @Input() loading = false;
  @Input() value!: string;
}
```

in the running up it works nice but when 
I go to test the test fails

```
it('should show spinner when loading true', () => {
    component.loading = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const strong = debugElement.query(By.css('strong'));
    const el: HTMLElement = strong.nativeElement;
    expect(el).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

Whats the right way to test component
with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

### UPDATE

Waiting in a better solution I worked it out
with:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SpinnerComponent]
    })
      .overrideComponent(SpinnerComponent, {
        set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default }
      })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12313

Comment: You have to create a proxy component when you use `OnPush`.

Comment: @Reactgular can you kindly give me an example, please?

Comment: omg, the hours I spent b/c something wasn't rendering in the unit tests...

Comment: The best answer here is the one about the TestHostComponent. For one, it tests the component the way a component is actually hosted in the app. Second, it does not change how the component-under-test works. You should try to avoid changing how the component works from a test.

Answer (score 10):

What works is to override component's **changeDetection to default** *AND*  provide **ComponentFixtureAutoDetect as true**.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [SpinnerComponent],
    providers: [
      {provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true}
    ]
  })
  .overrideComponent(SpinnerComponent, {
    set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default }
  })
  .compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SpinnerComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
}));
```

Now `fixture.detectChanges()` should work in the tests.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to provide TestingHostComponent that wraps a component you want to test:

```js
@Component({
  template: `<app-spinner [loading]="loading"></app-spinner>`
})
class TestHostComponent {
  @ViewChild(SpinnerComponent, { static: true }) spinnerComponent?: SpinnerComponent;

  loading?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: @user3887366 please, let me know if that helped, if so - please mark the answer as resolved

Answer (score 3):

I've tried many ways (including @Tschonner's answer) but none of them worked well. Finally, I got this working with the followings, using runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture) instead of fixture.detectChanges():

```
export async function runOnPushChangeDetection<T>(cf: ComponentFixture<T>) {
  const cd = cf.debugElement.injector.get<ChangeDetectorRef>(
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    ChangeDetectorRef as any
  );
  cd.markForCheck();
  cd.detectChanges();
  await cf.whenStable();
  return;
}

...

beforeEach(async() => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            IonicModule.forRoot()
        ],
        declarations: [ LoaderComponent ],
    })
    .overrideComponent(LoaderComponent, {
        set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default }
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should ...', async() => {
    component.prop = true;
    await runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture);

    const debugElement: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const compiled = debugElement.nativeElement;
    const img = debugElement.query(By.css('img'));
    expect(img).toBeDefined();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an improved utility function based on Akos Hamori answer:

```
export async function runOnPushChangeDetection<T>(fixture: ComponentFixture<T>): Promise<void> {
    const cd = fixture.debugElement.injector.get<ChangeDetectorRef>(ChangeDetectorRef);
    cd.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
        it('...',  async () => {
            //. do
            //. your
            //. stuff

            await runOnPushChangeDetection(fixture);
            expect(...)
        });
```