# Angular unit test component's @Input. Change value detection

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I have a simple scenario where (angular 17.3) I'm trying to test is the component reacts when the input property is changed.
I have a property passed from a parent component where it comes as @Input in the child. Something like that:

*parent*
...
`title = 'Hola!'`
...

Markup of the parent:

```
...
<my-child-component [input_title]="title" />
...
```

in the child:

```
....
@Input({ required: true }) input_title: String = '';
..
...
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const simpleChange = changes['input_title'];
    if (simpleChange.previousValue && (simpleChange.currentValue !== simpleChange.previousValue)) { 
      this.init(); // I WANT to test this method
    }
  }
...
```

So basically, I want to test this method and trigger changes. Furthermore more I want to test the change in the title. How can I do that from my unit test?

I have something like:

```
  let component: SimpleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SimpleComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SimpleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

...
  it('should change the title of the component', () => {
    const playSpy = spyOn(component, 'init');
    console.log(component?.input_title);
    const newTitle= 'blablabla';
    component.input_title= newTitle;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    console.log(compiled.querySelector('h1')?.textContent);
  });
```

and this isn't working :)

Comment: Do you use OnPush strategy? If so, it is known problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883314/angular-unit-test-with-changedetectionstrategy-onpush-doesnt-work), try to trigger cdr of component  (check answer with runOnPushChangeDetection 
 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883314/angular-unit-test-with-changedetectionstrategy-onpush-doesnt-work)

Comment: You might be looking for [ComponentRef#setInput](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#setInput) method

Comment: To be honest, I have checked out this strategy as I've been on ReactJS and Angukar skilss are a bit rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a test host component ([which is my and Angular's suggested strategy](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host)) you can make this work; EVEN WITH OnPush. I've taken liberties with what your init method might do - long story short you need to set your title twice because that is how you've written your on changes.

Html for simple component

```
<div id="initStatus">initialized: {{initialized}}</div>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child-component',

  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrl: './simple.component.css'
})
export class SimpleComponent implements OnChanges {
  initialized = false;
 
  @Input({ required: true }) input_title: String = '';

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const simpleChange = changes['input_title'];
    if (simpleChange.previousValue && (simpleChange.currentValue !== simpleChange.previousValue)) {
      this.init(); // I WANT to test this method
    }
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.initialized = true;
  }
}
```

spec file

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SimpleComponent } from './simple.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component(({
  template: `<my-child-component [input_title]="title"></my-child-component>`,
}))
class TestHostComponent {
  title = 'first title';

}

describe('SimpleComponent', () => {
  let component: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SimpleComponent, TestHostComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should init', () => {
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#initStatus'));
    expect(debugElement.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('initialized: false');

    component.title = 'second title'; // here is what you are missing
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(debugElement.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('initialized: true');
  });
});
```

Now, let's discuss ngOnChanges. It runs for EVERY CHANGE, which is why I avoid it entirely to help prevent performance issues.
Here is the new ts file that does the same thing but with a setter and OnPush

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child-component',

  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrl: './simple.component.css',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SimpleComponent {
  currentTitle: string
  initialized = false;

  @Input({ required: true }) set input_title(value: string) {
    const changed = !!this.currentTitle;
    this.currentTitle = value;
    if (changed) {
      this.init();
    }
  }

  private init(): void {
    this.initialized = true;
  }
}
```

Writing it out this way makes it a bit more obvious that your init is only called when you are changing an existing title.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @Sergey the OnPush issue you mention is best solved by using a test host as shown above. The other suggestions change how the component works, which invalidates the tests.

Comment: But it could be better in performance, as @segey mentioned.

Comment: Sorry but I probably missed - my component is stand stand-alone set to true. If I leave it as it is - I'm getting an error in the tests.

Comment: Also, I need it like this as the component actually embeds a Videogular instance. I have this onChanges trigger, and it calls the init() method. In my case, I need a way to change the input_title from (to maybe inside if possible) and have a spy on the init method for example. By changing your example (which works) to standalone: true I'm entering in a complicated scenario.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question and tag me. I looked a bit at the Videogular project and I think you'll also want to make a mock component to represent the videogular and what you pass to it. I'm a fan of testing the interaction with any child component being displayed from the html.

Comment: I see, but this is something depper in terms of testing. I was looking only to test an Input of the child component containing Videogular indeed. Changing that input I wat to test a method, exactly as per your example., but the component is made as snad-alone.